# PFQueryTableViewController Remove Cell Animated (Parse.com)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and the PFQueryTableViewController to display a list of posts from Parse which is displaying them fine. I wish to allow the user to swipe the cell left and delete the cell which will remove it from Parse and fade it from the UI.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

Which enables the nice iOS8 editing style. Here's where the problems start. When I hit the delete button, I can see my message being logged in the console:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in
        println("DELETE•ACTION");
    });

    return [deleteRowAction];
}
```

However the following never gets called:

```
override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        var object = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        println("good start")
        // The following lines means the project can't build because self.objects is of type NSArray not NSMutableArray
        self.objects.removeAtIndex(indexpath)
        object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Bool, NSError) -> Void in
            self.loadObjects()
            println("its alive...sort of")
        })
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

So the problems really are twofold.

### **Problem 1**

My commitEditingStyle doesn't seem to be getting called when I press the delete button? My silly log messages aren't being printed to the console

### **Problem 2**

I can't remove the object at the indexpath because in a PFQueryTableViewController, self.objects is an NSArray. I'm not sure how to get round with this? I'd read something about overriding the objectsDidLoad method and creating an NSMutableArray from self.objects or creating a subclass, but there were no details and I don't understand how I could change the datasource of the table from self.objects to self.myNewMutableArray for example

I've seen a few similar answers but nothing clearcut so far. I don't mind if the answer is in obj C, I just need to understand the principles of what I need to do.

### UPDATE

Problem one is solved as per Rory McKinnel's answer.

For problem 2 I created the following subclass:

```
class EditablePFQueryTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController{

var editableObjects: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError!) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(NSError())
    editableObjects = NSMutableArray(array: self.objects)

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
    var object = self.editableObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    return object
}

// overriding this to try and make sure the number of rows is accurate
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var numberOfRows = self.editableObjects.count
    return numberOfRows
}

}
```

And added:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in
        println("DELETE•ACTION");
        var object = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        self.editableObjects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Bool, NSError) -> Void in
            self.loadObjects()
            println("its alive")
        })
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    });

    return [deleteRowAction];
}
```

which seems to work fine

Comment: For problem 2, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31361625/4139760), you can just add `self.tableView.reloadData()` after `self.loadObjects()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` lets you return the actions to be taken, and when selected will fire the handler you registered and nothing else. You have to put all your delete code in the handler. You could call `commitEditingStyle` yourself from within the handler you registered. This is why you see the NSLog message and nothing else.

If you want it to call `commitEditingStyle` for you, then you need to implement the following method from which you return the editing style you want for the indexPath passed. It will then call `commitEditingStyle`when activated by the user.

```
  optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
```

So you have to use one or the other.

Comment: got it. Thanks for the answer, good explanation as well! Any clues on the Parse stuff (Problem 2)?

Comment: You could try overriding the `getObjects` getter and using your own array of objects which could start as [super.objects mutableCopy]. However a lot would depend on whether the PF class uses _objects internally or self.objects internally. It does not seem well suited to being edited. Try overriding getObjects to see if that works. Not even sure if you are allowed to do that in objc. Otherwise I think you will need to use the delete notification to delete the data in parse, then reload the table or write your own UITableViewController if deleting the real objects is not an option.

Comment: I think I need to subclass PFQueryTableController to create a mutable array from self.objects and then override the `objectAtIndexPath` to return the relevant object from my mutable array rather than self.objects. That way I can call removeAtIndex(indexpath) at will

Comment: Unfortunately the table will still get numberOfRowsForSection wrong as it will base it on its internal self.objects.count size. So it will end up asking you via objectAtIndexPath for the original number of rows. Hence my suggestion that unless you can override getObjects, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: I was hoping I could just override the numberOfRowsInSection method to return a count of the editableObjects which would have been updated?

Comment: That might work. A lot will depend on how the PF table handles all the other delegate calls like heightForRowAtIndexPath etc... All you can do is try it and see what happens.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the code I used. following your suggestions it seems to work, thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem...it seems strange that Parse doesn't include a method with a reference to object for editing like they do for cellForRowAtIndexPath?