# When delete cell and [self loadObjects] in PFQueryTableViewController, it gets Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am willing to delete cell and show reload tableView in cell of PFQueryViewController.

But, when I delete and refresh TableView, I have get error:" *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582"

After this error code, I check data in Parse, and the data of deleted cell is deleted.

I watched this Link, but I am not sure why get assertion in my code.
When I use  [self loadObjects].
https://parse.com/questions/refresh-data-in-a-pfquerytableviewcontroller

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
     PFObject * object = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
     [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
         if (succeeded) {
             [self loadObjects];
         }else{
         }
     }];
```

Could you please give me some advice ?

Comment: You should include more of the actual error message - there should be more information than `assertion failure`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can only get this error code as I wrote.                            2015-07-12 01:18:35.347 ParseStarterProject[19979:4424938] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2015-07-12 01:18:36.098 ParseStarterProject[19979:4424938] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582

Comment: So did you set a breakpoint on `warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, after upgrading to a newer parse sdk. Don't know what version exactly, but here's how I solved my Assertion Failure, simply by calling `reloadData` after `loadObjects`:

```
PFObject * object = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
 [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
     if (succeeded) {
         [self loadObjects];
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     }else{
        //handle your error
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Thank you for the critical advice !!  I did it thanks to your precious advice. Thank you very much :)

Comment: So the above answer solved your problem? Parse must have changed something in the `loadObjects` method ...

Comment: I had the same problem. If you use the debugger step by step, you will see how - (BFTask *)loadObjects:(NSInteger)page clear:(BOOL)clear  calls [self.tableView reloadData]; However I don't understand it doesn't work. BTW your solution works for me, thanks. Perhaps it's because of BFTask, I remember in old versions that was not in loadObject.

Comment: >>Eric  yup, thanks to your advice, I solved it.   >>Ricardo  Thank you for the information, I will check BFTask thanks :)

Comment: Nice. I Battled with this for a few hours using one or the other of these two calls. Never thought to use them in concert. Evil genius! Thanks for the leg up!