# iOS - PFQueryTableViewController - Delete Row crashes

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using PFQueryTableViewController with Local Datastore. I want to enable user to delete a object from the table with this code:

```
 // Override to support editing the table view.
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
     // Delete the row from the data source

         PFObject * object = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

         [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock: ^ (BOOL succeeded, NSError * error) {
             [self loadObjects];
         }];

         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
     else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
     // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
     }
  }
```

I get this 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

---

I think, this is a comment use in a PFQueryTableViewController but I can´t find the solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete objects from an array, your changing the structure of your `UITableView`

Lets say you start off with 100 objects in an array called `objectsArray`.

- numberOfRowsInSection = return objectsArray.count (i.e, 100)
- cellsForRowAtIndexPath = 100 cells, or however many that will be reused to show all 100 objects

Now you just deleted some rows from the `UITableView` here : `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:....]`
So lets say you deleted 3 rows from `objectsArray`, that means you deleted the tangible rows from the `UITableView` so the `UITableView` thinks `numberOfRows..` = 100 - 3. But it doesn't, because you haven't updated your array to subtract those 3 objects that you just deleted.

So you are actually reloading the tableView `[self loadObjects]` before those tangible 3 rows are deleted, or maybe after in your case because the `inBackground` part. So in other words, your reloading `objectsArray` again before you are trying to animate the rows out that you deleted from the tableView. This can't happen fast enough, especially since you put it in an asynchronous callback, you probably shouldn't do that for performance sake. So in short, you need to update your array *after* you delete the rows so `numberOfRowsInSection` will always reflect the correct number of objects

If your data is sensitive and you *need* to wait to see if the callback returns a successful `deleteInBackground` then you should also update your tableView there, because you never know when that method will actually finish:

```
..deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
      //get main thread
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [self loadObjects];
    } else {
      //error in deleting them 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this code I get other error: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:1623 I am investigating what this error means. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Finally I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358082/when-delete-cell-and-self-loadobjects-in-pfquerytableviewcontroller-it-gets-a

Comment: Oh shoot. Sorry I meant to actually change this but got side tracked by other questions and forgot to come back. Sorry. That error was a given